# 'django_1 | no port[s] to connect to' after running docker-compose up

Tags: django, docker

I am new to docker, and have written a containerized django app, and react app. When I go to run `docker-compose up` I get a weird, perpetuating error that django has no port(s) to connect to. Running the server from the react and python side both work.

**Error message**

[image]
**Frontend dockerfile:**

```
COPY ./react_app/package.json .
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
        python \
        make \
        g++ \
    && npm install \
    && apk del .gyp

COPY ./react_app .

ARG API_SERVER
ENV REACT_APP_API_SERVER=${API_SERVER}
RUN REACT_APP_API_SERVER=${API_SERVER} \ 
  npm run build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install -g serve
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build ./build
Django Python backend Dockerfile

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.7.9-slim-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends netcat && \
   apt-get autoremove -y && \
   apt-get clean && \
   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY ./django_app .

RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
and the nginx dockerfile

FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

**Django Python backend Dockerfile**

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.7.9-slim-stretch
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends netcat && \
   apt-get autoremove -y && \
   apt-get clean && \
   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY ./django_app .

RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**and the nginx dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.19.10-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

My entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."
    
    while ! nc -z $DB_HOST $DB_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done
    
    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py migrate --noinput
echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User;
User.objects.filter(email='$DJANGO_ADMIN_EMAIL').delete();
User.objects.create_superuser('$DJANGO_ADMIN_USER', '$DJANGO_ADMIN_EMAIL', '$DJANGO_ADMIN_PASSWORD')" | python manage.py shell

exec "$@"
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - django_static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    command: gunicorn candle.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./postgres/.env
  react:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - API_SERVER=${ENV_API_SERVER}
    volumes:
      - react_static_volume:/usr/src/app/build/static
    expose:
      - 3000
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: serve -s build -l 3000
    depends_on:
      - django

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - django_static_volume:/usr/src/app/django_files/static
      - react_static_volume:/usr/src/app/react_files/static
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - react

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  django_static_volume:
  react_static_volume:
```

Nginx Config

```
upstream django_backend {
    server django:8000;
}

upstream react_frontend {
    server react:3000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    ###########
    # URL ROUTING #
    ###########

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://django_backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://django_backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    ###########
    # STATIC FOLDER ROUTING #
    ###########

    location /static/admin/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/django_files/static/admin/;
    }

    location /static/rest_framework/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/django_files/static/rest_framework/;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/react_files/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/media/;
    }

    ###########
    # URL ROUTING #
    ###########

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://react_frontend;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }


}
```

I can't find anything related to this, and I also am new to Docker.

Comment: Share `entrypoint.sh` in django docker, and your `docker-compose` file pls

Comment: Just added each, thanks @Amin

Comment: Sorry, and your nginx conf too

Comment: Just put it up. Thanks @Amin

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message? Is it from entrypoint.sh, or some error within Django? If it's an error within Django, is there a traceback?

Comment: Can you add ports: to the django on docker-compose file and try again? You're exposing port 8000 but you didn't define any port on django container. That's probably the reason because it says there's no port to connect.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın, I just added ```    ports:
      - 8000:8000``` to the django's docker-compose file; however, this gives me the same error.

Comment: @NickODell I have just added a ss of the full error message to the post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a netcat error. Specifically, it occurs when you provide a hostname but not a port while running `nc`.

Example:

```
# nc -z 8.8.8.8
no port[s] to connect to
```

Then, your entrypoint script sees that netcat exited with an error, and re-runs it until it succeeds, which it never will.

## Debugging process

I suspected that this was a netcat problem because the entrypoint script prints "Waiting for postgres..." but not "PostgreSQL started." However, I couldn't get netcat to produce the "no port" error.

So I ran a copy of the base image, and manually installed netcat.

```
docker run -it python:3.7.9-slim-stretch bash
# in container
apt-get update
apt-get install netcat
```

I still couldn't get netcat to produce the error. So I downloaded the source code of netcat:

```
# still in container
apt-get source netcat
```

Then, armed with a copy of the [source code of netcat](https://gist.github.com/nickodell/309eafee6f8474279c368b7fb7523824), I found this code:

```
  if (argv[optind] == NULL)
    bail ("no port[s] to connect to");
```

Translation: If the argument parsing code, which has just finished parsing the host value, runs out of arguments, then emit the "no port[s] to connect to" error.

We can check this by running nc inside the container:

```
root@cc139fd40237:/source/netcat-1.10# nc -z localhost
no port[s] to connect to
```

Interestingly, Ubuntu has a different version of netcat, with a different error message.

```
$ nc -z localhost
nc: missing port number
```

...so that was why I couldn't reproduce the netcat error outside the container!

## Robust shell scripts

In this line, either DB_HOST or DB_PORT is unset:

```
while ! nc -z $DB_HOST $DB_PORT; do
```

Besides just fixing the problem, this is a good opportunity to make your script more robust. If you add `set -u` to the top of your shell script, you would've gotten a vastly more helpful error message instead:

```
Waiting for postgres...
entrypoint.sh: 7: DB_PORT: parameter not set
```

You can also use the [shellcheck tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) - on your script, it recommends that you quote arguments:

```sh
In entrypoint.sh line 6:
    while ! nc -z $DB_HOST $DB_PORT; do
                  ^------^ SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                           ^------^ SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: 
    while ! nc -z "$DB_HOST" "$DB_PORT"; do
```

which is also an excellent idea.

Comment: Hey Nick. Thanks for the awesome, informative answer. I've previously identified the host and ports for the postgres db in my python's `local_settings`. This must not be the right spot because, like you said, the `$DB_PORT` or `$DB_HOST` is null. In which file do I set these variables?

Comment: Those are environment variables, which can be [set in a compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file).

Comment: for me `$DB_PORT` was missing the .env, thanks.

Comment: @JosephAdam I'm surprised this error happened to more than one person. Are both of you installing the same software?

Comment: @NickODell same tutorial :)